# Jquery - Insert value on append element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I insert value on `<input type="text">` but this element is from append method. Here'is the code

HTML

```
<input type="email" name="invite_people" placeholder="Invite someone">
  <a href="#!" class="add_people">Add People</a>
  <div class="people_invite">
    <!-- Here is <input type="text" name="people_invited" readonly> is added by jquery -->
  </div>
```

Jquery

```
$(".add_people").click(function () {
   var orang_yg_diinvite = $("input type='text' name='invite_people'>").val();
   $(".people_invite").append("<input type='text' name='people_invited' readonly>");
});
```

It success for append `<input type="text" name="people_invited" readonly>` inside `<div class="people_invite">`, but I want to make `<input type="text" name="people_invited" readonly>` have an value from **var orang_yg_diinvite** . How can I do that? Please help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's mutliple ways to do that:

> Just directly add it to the HTML of the input you're appending

```
$(".people_invited").append("<input type='text' value='"+orang_yg_diinvite+"'>");
```

Or

> Edit your input's value after it was appended

```
$(".people_invited").append("<input type='text'>");
$(".people_invited>input").val(orang_yg_diinvite);
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(".add_people").click(function () {
   var orang_yg_diinvite = $("input[name='invite_people']").val();
   $(".people_invited").append("<input type='text' value='"+orang_yg_diinvite+"'>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="email" name="invite_people" placeholder="Invite someone">
<a href="#!" class="add_people">Add People</a>
<div class="people_invited">
</div>
```

Comment: I love it, speacially for the second way. Thanks for the answers!!

Comment: Can't you just chain the action like so: $(".people_invited").append("<input type='text' />").val(orang_yg_diinvite); ?

Comment: @REJH No, since `.val()` would be applied to `$(".people_invited")`, not to the input.

Comment: Ah right. I wasn't sure if append() returns the appended element. I guess you need to use insertBefore() or insertAfter()

Answer (score 1):

You can pass directly in `value` attribute of `input`

```js
$(".add_people").click(function() {
  var v = $("input[name='invite_people']").val();
  $(".people_invited").append(`<input readonly type="text" value=${v} >`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="email" name="invite_people" placeholder="Invite someone">
<a href="#!" class="add_people">Add People</a>
<div class="people_invited">
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create element using [jQuery( html, attributes )](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes) method, Here you can set HTML attributes

```
var input = $("<input/>", { type: 'text', value : orang_yg_diinvite})
$(".people_invited").append(input);
```

```js
$(".add_people").click(function() {
  var orang_yg_diinvite = $("input[name='invite_people']").val();
  var input = $("<input/>", {
    type: 'text',
    value: orang_yg_diinvite
  })
  $(".people_invited").append(input);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="email" name="invite_people" placeholder="Invite someone">
<a href="#!" class="add_people">Add People</a>
<div class="people_invited">
  <!-- Here is <input type="text" name="people_invited" readonly> is added by jquery -->
</div>
```

Comment: @BariqDharmawan, You should use jQuery ways of creating element rather than using string concatenation. It will save you from lots of mess. Testing with quotes (`", '`) as input or stick with `val()` method

Answer (score 1):

You can also add `value` and `readonly` attribute while appending input string.

```
$(".add_people").click(function () {
   var orang_yg_diinvite = $("input[name='invite_people']").val();
   $(".people_invited").append("<input type='text' name='people_invited' value='"+ orang_yg_diinvite +"' readonly />");
});
```